# Web and Mobile Analytics - Conversion tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics

I am having some issues capturing conversions in SFMC Web and Mobile Analytics. I was hoping someone could let me know what is truly required when it comes to conversion tracking. I have dropped the below JavaScript on the conversion page I am testing:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://6321501.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "6321501"]);
    _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]); 
    _etmc.push(["trackConversion", {"cart" : [{
                                              "item" : "Subscription",
                                              "quantity" : "1",
                                              "price" : "999"
                                             }],
                                   }
              ]);
</script>
```

I was assuming that is all that is required to capture a conversion. Can anyone confirm if the above is the only information that needs to be passed to capture a conversion in SFMC Web and Mobile Analytics? I can confirm I can capture a a standard conversion using JavaScript to pass the information back to https://click.s6.exacttarget.com/conversion.aspx using XML.

Thanks for any help

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party and the solution isn't as straightforward as one might think it could be but for the most part you are on the right track.

What you have above would enable the capturing of aggregated conversion details within the Web and Mobile Analytics tool in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

However, this would not give you email revenue attribution.  In order to see how many conversions/how much revenue came from any given email campaign, you would also want to follow these instructions in conjunction with the Discovery tool in SFMC:

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/discover/email_revenue_attribution/

Note that at the date of this answer, a notification still exists on the above help documentation page stating that a Services Engagement is required of SFMC to implement this feature.